# MS Word 2010 : Cannot Print Page Range of .doc File

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2010

I need to specify a page range to print in MS Word 2010 - the file in question is a .doc. Under the `Print` menu, the `Pages` field is grayed out. If I try to convert the file to .docx it completely messes up the formatting.

I know that this is achievable on a .doc in Word 2010 because I've created a blank .doc in which the `Pages` option is not grayed out. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!